# trying to resize an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, resizable

Ok, I've tried two solutions from here (forums and so far nothing has happened) here is my code:

```
<script>
<!---tried this without success-->
$("#mySupport").resizable();
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
<!--also tried this from the forums-->
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mySupport', window.parent.document).height($(document).height());
});

</script>
<iframe id="mySupport" width="960" height="900" seamless src="https://enterraglobal.zendesk.com/"  scrolling="no">



</iframe>
<!--I don't know probably I'm missing something-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mySupport").height("100px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to set the iframe to the same size as the outer document. If so:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#mySupport').height( $(document).height() ); 
    $('#mySupport').width( $(document).width() ); 
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6YHL/)